# How I can get the text and put in another text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a Windows Forms app, and I want to copy data from `test.txt`, text file in `test2.txt`. In test.txt I have the next rows :

```
Licfile="C:\temp\lic.lic"
Output="C:\temp\out.log"
Title="name"
```

and in `test2.txt` I have :

```
outlog=
license=
lmgr_files=
license_path=
```

and I want to have something like this

```
outlog="C:\temp\out.log"
license_path="C:\temp\lic.lic"
lmgr_files=false
license=true
```

As you can see I need a code without mention  the number of rows, and the name of fields are different. For this I tried this code :

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
    var link = File.ReadLines(path + "test.txt").ToArray();
    foreach (var txt in link)
    {
        if (txt.Contains("Output="))
        {
            var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
            if (File.Exists(path + "test2.txt")) File.AppendAllText(path + "test2.txt", outputPath);
            else
            {
                File.AppendAllText(path + "test2.txt", "outlog =" + outputPath);
            }
        }
        else if (txt.Contains("Licfile="))
        {
            var LicFilePath = txt.Split('=')[1];
            if (File.Exists(path + "test2.txt")) File.AppendAllText(path + "test2.txt", LicFilePath);
            else
            {
                File.AppendAllText(path + "test2.txt", "license_path =" + LicFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this not do all the task, and when I run in test2.txt appear :

```
outlog=
license_path="C:\temp\out.log""C:\temp\lic.lic"
lmgr_files=
license=
```

How I can make this to work properly, and it's not a simply way, to do this ?

In my code I used this code to get the `Title` and put in `TEXT` of a frame, 
but I don't know how to use between two text file

```
this.Text = File.ReadLines(link)
                .First(x => x.StartsWith("Title=\""))
                .Split(new[] { '=', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Comment: If you are going to just `.ToArray()` your `ReadLines`, then you might as well just use `ReadAllLines` instead. But in this case since you just iterate over `link`, drop the `.ToArray()` and just use the `IEnumerable<string>` that `ReadLines` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for loop. If you have only this static data. Try this:

```
                //Started from array of strings - (you may read from file and put in the arrays)

                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string[] text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path + "test.txt");
                string[] text2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path + "test2.txt");

                text2[0] = text2[0] + text1.Where(x => x.Split('=')[0] == "Output").FirstOrDefault().Split('=')[1];
                text2[1] = text2[1] + text1.Where(x => x.Split('=')[0] == "Licfile").FirstOrDefault().Split('=')[1];    
                text2[2] = text2[2] + "false";
                text2[3] = text2[3] + "true";

                //Now the result variable will contain the final text, you can write in a file.
                string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text2);
```

Comment: yes but, if I modify the order of the rows I need to modify the code, and I don't want to do this. I want something like this  this.Text = File.ReadLines(link)
                .First(x => x.StartsWith("Title=\"")).....

Comment: Now you added another key 'Title' ? not mentioned in any of the file text in original question ?

Comment: that title is not important for the test2.txt, this is the reason way I doesn't mentioned

Comment: I need to replace text2 with test2, and the begin to put  string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            var link = File.ReadLines(path + "test.txt").ToArray(); ??

Comment: and when I put this code after  private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {It is supposed to work??? or it's necessary to declare something else ?

Comment: sure, and i assumed you already change declaration for text1 in the same way.

Comment: please you can say what i need to put before your code ?

Comment: if is not so mach for you, you can put all the code here ?

Comment: in test2.txt 

nothing appears

Comment: you get the final text in 'result' variable. do yo also want me to write code write this in test file. this you already done.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most comes from the use of `File.AppendAllText()`, this adds a new line to the file which is not what you seem to be wishing to do.

When you manipulate such files, you should rebuild the whole file. The only counter argument would be handling of large files... but that's not the case.

Read the input arguments of the second file and extend them with the input of the first file, then write the whole result in the file.

*Edit: edited due to new information provided*

```
//I have no IDE at the moment so it's pseudo C#
//Have you tried something like this?
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
var linkFirstFile = File.ReadLines(path + "test.txt").ToArray();
var linkSecondFile = File.ReadLines(path + "test2.txt").ToArray();

var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"outlog=", "Output"},
    {"license=", ""},
    {"lmgr_files=", ""},
    {"license_path=", "Licfile"},
};

foreach(var part in linkSecondFile)
{
    part += linkFirstFile.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(mapping[part]))
}

File.WriteAllLines(path2, linkSecondFile);
```

Comment: ... and? Where does this Title come from? It's kind of hard to give you an answer in the first place... but if you add some foreign elements like this it is harder and harder...

Comment: My data is not order, that I mentioned that I doesn't want to put the number of rows

Comment: Just look at the structure, I want to help you to see what I want to say. I want to search in test2.txt where I have outlog and after equal to copy what is after Output= from test1.txt

Comment: it doesn't work and I made the change part to path and path2 to path